# Objective C - Name+Name.m naming convention

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes I see Name+Name.m naming convention for a file in an XCode project.
What does that mean?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it means that the file in question contains the code for a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1).